# sql - performing join when matching value is in between two column values

Tags: sql, join

I have a table1 like below, table1 is very huge

```
Col1 Col2
A     1
B     5
A     7
```

My table2 is as below. My real table2 is very big and I cannot explode it due to size restrictions.

```
Col3 Col4  Col5
0     2      x
4     5.5    y
6     7.5    z
```

In such case is there a way to join table1 and table2 such that `where table1.col2 is between table2.col3 and table2.col4`

The output that I want is below

```
Col1 Col2 Col5
A     1    x
B     5    y
A     7    z
```

Comment: Which `DBMS` you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `INNER JOIN` with `BETWEEN` as `join` condition

```
SELECT t1.col1, 
       t1.col2, 
       t2.col5 
FROM   table1 t1 
       JOIN table2 t2 
         ON t1.col2 BETWEEN t2.col3 AND t2.col4
```

**Note :** you have mentioned *where table1>>col2 is between table2>>col4 and table2>>col5* but it should be *where table1>>col2 is between **table2>>col3** and **table2>>col4***

Comment: i updated my post to reflect `table1>>col2 is between table2>>col3 and table2>>col4`

Comment: @user2543622 - yes I can see

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
SELECT
    t1.col1
  , t1.col2
  , t2.col5
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.col2 BETWEEN t2.col3 AND t2.col4
```